# Constraining the Domain of Voronoi Vertices Generated by Qhull

Tags: numpy, scipy, geometry, computational-geometry, qhull

My question in short: Is it possible to constrain the domain of the Voronoi vertices generated by Qhull? If so, how can one do so?

My question with context: I am working on a data visualization in which I have points in a 2D field. The points overlap a bit, so I'm "jittering" them slightly so as to make them not overlap.

My current approach to this task is to use [Lloyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm) to move the points. Lloyd's algorithm essentially takes the initial point positions, computes a Voronoi map, and moves each point to the center of its Voronoi region during each iteration of the algorithm.

Here's an example in Python:

```
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
from scipy.spatial import voronoi_plot_2d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys

class Field():
  '''
  Create a Voronoi map that can be used to run Lloyd relaxation on an array of 2D points.
  For background, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm
  '''

  def __init__(self, arr):
    '''
    Store the points and bounding box of the points to which Lloyd relaxation will be applied
    @param [arr] arr: a numpy array with shape n, 2, where n is number of points
    '''
    if not len(arr):
      raise Exception('please provide a numpy array with shape n,2')

    x = arr[:, 0]
    y = arr[:, 0]
    self.bounding_box = [min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)]
    self.points = arr
    self.build_voronoi()

  def build_voronoi(self):
    '''
    Build a Voronoi map from self.points. For background on self.voronoi attrs, see:
    https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Voronoi.html
    '''
    eps = sys.float_info.epsilon
    self.voronoi = Voronoi(self.points)
    self.filtered_regions = [] # list of regions with vertices inside Voronoi map
    for region in self.voronoi.regions:
      inside_map = True    # is this region inside the Voronoi map?
      for index in region: # index = the idx of a vertex in the current region

          # check if index is inside Voronoi map (indices == -1 are outside map)
          if index == -1:
            inside_map = False
            break

          # check if the current coordinate is in the Voronoi map's bounding box
          else:
            coords = self.voronoi.vertices[index]
            if not (self.bounding_box[0] - eps <= coords[0] and
                    self.bounding_box[1] + eps >= coords[0] and
                    self.bounding_box[2] - eps <= coords[1] and
                    self.bounding_box[3] + eps >= coords[1]):
              inside_map = False
              break

      # store hte region if it has vertices and is inside Voronoi map
      if region != [] and inside_map:
        self.filtered_regions.append(region)

  def find_centroid(self, vertices):
    '''
    Find the centroid of a Voroni region described by `vertices`, and return a
    np array with the x and y coords of that centroid.

    The equation for the method used here to find the centroid of a 2D polygon
    is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_polygon

    @params: np.array `vertices` a numpy array with shape n,2
    @returns np.array a numpy array that defines the x, y coords
      of the centroid described by `vertices`
    '''
    area = 0
    centroid_x = 0
    centroid_y = 0
    for i in range(len(vertices)-1):
      step = (vertices[i, 0] * vertices[i+1, 1]) - (vertices[i+1, 0] * vertices[i, 1])
      area += step
      centroid_x += (vertices[i, 0] + vertices[i+1, 0]) * step
      centroid_y += (vertices[i, 1] + vertices[i+1, 1]) * step
    area /= 2
    centroid_x = (1.0/(6.0*area)) * centroid_x
    centroid_y = (1.0/(6.0*area)) * centroid_y
    return np.array([centroid_x, centroid_y])

  def relax(self):
    '''
    Moves each point to the centroid of its cell in the Voronoi map to "relax"
    the points (i.e. jitter them so as to spread them out within the space).
    '''
    centroids = []
    for region in self.filtered_regions:
      vertices = self.voronoi.vertices[region + [region[0]], :]
      centroid = self.find_centroid(vertices) # get the centroid of these verts
      centroids.append(list(centroid))

    self.points = centroids # store the centroids as the new point positions
    self.build_voronoi() # rebuild the voronoi map given new point positions

##
# Visualize
##

# built a Voronoi diagram that we can use to run lloyd relaxation
field = Field(points)

# plot the points with no relaxation relaxation
plt = voronoi_plot_2d(field.voronoi, show_vertices=False, line_colors='orange', line_alpha=0.6, point_size=2)
plt.show()

# relax the points several times, and show the result of each relaxation
for i in range(6): 
  field.relax() # the .relax() method performs lloyd relaxation
  plt = voronoi_plot_2d(field.voronoi, show_vertices=False, line_colors='orange', line_alpha=0.6, point_size=2)
  plt.show()
```

As we can see, during each iteration (frames 2 and 3) the points in the original dataset (frame 1, top) overlap less and less, which is great!

[image]

The trouble with this approach is I'm currently removing from the plot those points whose voronoi region boundaries lie beyond the domain of the initial dataset. (If I don't do that, the outermost points quickly shoot out into hyperspace and move very far from the rest of the points.) This ultimately means I end up discarding points, which is no good.

I thought I could solve this problem by constraining the Qhull Voronoi domain so as to only create Voronoi vertices within the original data domain.

Is it possible to constrain Qhull in this way? Any help others can offer would be greatly appreciated!

---

#### Update

After receiving @tfinniga's excellent response I put together a [blog post](https://douglasduhaime.com/posts/lloyd-iteration.html) detailing Lloyd iteration in its bounded and unbounded forms. I also put together a little package [lloyd](https://github.com/duhaime/lloyd) to make it easier to run bounded Lloyd iterations on a dataset. I wanted to share these resources in case they help others pursuing related analysis.

Comment: What do you consider as "original data domain"? The convex hull?

Comment: @Ripi2 yes that would be great. I suppose I *was* thinking of the original data domain as just the min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y, but if it's possible to constrain by the hull, that's even better

Comment: If you already have the boundary then just prevent creating/moving a point beyond that boundary.

Comment: @Ripi2 yes, that's my plan but I thought it'd be simpler/cleaner/faster to push the work to Qhull (ie to ask Qhull not to create voronoi vertices beyond a specified domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core problem that you're running into is that there's nothing bounding Lloyd's algorithm, so the points explode.  Two ways to fix this:

1. Take the voronoi diagram you're getting, and manually clip it to your bounding rectangle before computing the centroid.  This will give you the correct solution - you can test it against the example you linked in the wikipedia article and make sure it matches.
2. Add an artificial boundary of points.  For example, you could add points at the 4 corners of your bounding box, or some along each side, which you don't move.  These will stop the interior points from exploding.  This won't give you the 'correct' result from Lloyd's algorithm, but might give you an output useful for your visualization, and is easier to implement.

Comment: absolutely perfect. Clipping the voronoi vertices left lots of points bunched at the edges (looks like the area of those cells approaches 0), but adding bounding points worked perfectly. Do you happen to know of any good books that discuss geometric algorithms like Lloyd iteration? I only discovered it through a stray tweet from a WebGL developer, and I'd like to read more about other interesting algorithms to do with graphics and geometry. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @duhaime Unfortunately, I don't know of a good resource to point you towards - I only learned of Lloyd's algorithm from your question.

Comment: BTW, if you're happy with the results you're getting I wouldn't mess with it, but there are some ways to fix the collapsed points - rather than setting each point to the centroid, you could move each point some percentage of the way towards the centroid.  Alternatively, you could have a more complex term for motion that includes a signed distance field, so that points are repelled from the edges of bounding rectangle.

Comment: amen thanks for your note. I thought about some kind of scalar that would control attraction towards a centroid, but a few iterations of moving points to the exact centroid is working for my particular problem at the moment. It's a neat trick!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither of the suggestions of @tfinniga gave me satisfactory results.

In my hands, artificial boundary points at the corners of the bounding box don't seem to constrain the layout. Boundary points seem to only work, if they are densely placed along the edges of the bounding box, which slows down the computation of the Voronoi tesselation considerably.

Naive clipping of either the Voronoi vertices or the computed Voronoi centroids to the bounding box works for points that only exceed the bounding box in one dimension. Otherwise, multiple points can end up being assigned to the same corner of the bounding box, which results in an undefined behaviour as the Voronoi tesselation is only defined for a set of unique positions.

Instead, in my implementation below, I simply do not update points, where the new position is outside the bounding box. The extra computation needed to constrain the layout is trivially small, and -- as far as I can tell from my testing -- this approach does not run into any breaking edge cases.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Implementation of a constrained Lloyds algorithm to remove node overlaps.
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi


def lloyds(positions, origin=(0,0), scale=(1,1), total_iterations=3):
    positions = positions.copy()
    for _ in range(total_iterations):
        centroids = _get_voronoi_centroids(positions)
        is_valid = _is_within_bbox(centroids, origin, scale)
        positions[is_valid] = centroids[is_valid]
    return positions


def _get_voronoi_centroids(positions):
    voronoi = Voronoi(positions)
    centroids = np.zeros_like(positions)
    for ii, idx in enumerate(voronoi.point_region):
        # ignore voronoi vertices at infinity
        # TODO: compute regions clipped by bbox
        region = [jj for jj in voronoi.regions[idx] if jj != -1]
        centroids[ii] = _get_centroid(voronoi.vertices[region])
    return centroids


def _get_centroid(polygon):
    # TODO: formula may be incorrect; correct one here:
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_polygon
    return np.mean(polygon, axis=0)


def _is_within_bbox(points, origin, scale):
    minima = np.array(origin)
    maxima = minima + np.array(scale)
    return np.all(np.logical_and(points >= minima, points <= maxima), axis=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    positions = np.random.rand(200, 2)
    adjusted = lloyds(positions)

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
    axes[0].plot(*positions.T, 'ko')
    axes[1].plot(*adjusted.T, 'ro')

    for ax in axes:
        ax.set_aspect('equal')

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```